# transferring a value between two separate blockchain networks built with Ethereum and corda

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, corda, solidity

I am facing an issue where I have to transfer a value from a private blockchain network to the public blockchain network.

A private blockchain network is built with Corda whereas the public blockchain network is built with Ethereum technology. As long as we are transferring values within an ethereum network we can use

```
address public transfertoaddress;

transfertoaddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

Here we know that any value (Token) e.g which is exist in the smart contract can be sent to any address as far as it exists on the Ethereum network like above code.

But what if a token must be sent to the private blockchain or sent by the private blockchain to the public blockchain. For instance, a private blockchain is built with CORDA technology how it can persist the token value or its ownership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send values between blockchains natively, they are different universes that are unaware of each other.

Using a third party atomic-swap-like thing you may be able to swap values simultaneously. It works like this: You give me this amount of tokens in X network and I give you that amount of tokens in Y network and we do this at the same time (both or none at all).